# Enable idling on Heroku paid dyno

Tags: heroku

I have a use case where I'd like my heroku dyno to idle when not in use. It is for an infrequently used service that requires a large server when in use (decent processor and 4g of memory). Consequently, to save money I'd like this dyno to idle / shut down after a short period of non-usage.

Is this possible? I haven't found a solution on the heroku docs.

If not, I'll have to create a small lightweight API service and dynamically spin up a new worker dyno when needed, but that is a bunch of code I don't want to write!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [autoidle](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/autoidle) which sounds like might fit your needs, other addons are available in dyno section [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).

If none of this works then like you said, you can use heroku platform api and use a scheduler to spin up and spin down the dynos.

Comment: this looks like a great option to explore, thank you!